# How to keep an object “persistent” in a C# dll?

Tags: c#, object, dll, object-persistence

I have written a dll in C#, offering a class for use. The dll is called by a C program that I have written. (It’s a plugin to some program. I have to write the plugin’s code in C, but I want to use the functionality of .NET, therefore the dll).

In the dll, I want to open up a stream and do other stuff that should be persistent between two calls to the dll. That is represented in the following code by the private member Connector.

```
namespace myCSharpDll
{
    // the c++ program calls this methods
    public interface IAccess
    {
        double Initialize();
        double Timestep(double time, double[] values);
        ...
    }

    // E is the beginning of another program my dll should connect to, therefore the names
    public class EAccess : IAccess
    {
        // EConnector is another class I defined in the same dll
        private EConnector Connector;

        public double InitializeE()
        {
            Connector = new EPConnector();
        }
        public double Timestep(double time, double[] values)
        {
            return Connector.Connect();
        }
```

When I make a call to InitializeE() and later one to Timestep() the Connector oject points to NULL.

What do I have to do that when I call Timestep() from my C code, that I can access the before created instance of Connector?

I probably search in the wrong direction at all. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Please show us your C++ code.  Also, C != C++.

Comment: Resolved. Thanks everybody. Thanks SLaks - going through my C/C++ code to show it to you showed me the bug. / Stackoverflow doesn't let me post the answer because I haven't collected enough reputation points. But it will let me in 8 hours. I post the answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks SLaks for asking for my C/C++ code. That is where the problem was located. It was simpler than I thought. I found the mistake while putting together the code to show you.

---

I know that C and C++ is not the same, the plugin structure is just a little weird. Most of the code was generated by a wizard. I just had to fill in my code. It's a cpp file, but the code seems to be C. Well, I think that is off topic.

Here it is, I extraced the most important lines.

```
// the dll is connected via COM, using the type library file that regasm generated
#import "[path]\myCSharpDll.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
using namespace myCSharpDll;

static void OnActivate (IfmDocument, Widget);

//off topic: this are the weird lines the wizard put in my way 
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif /* __cplusplus */

// when the plugin is called by the host program, this function is called
static void OnActivate (IfmDocument pDoc, Widget button)
{
    InitializeIntermediate(pDoc);
    Timestep1(...);
}

static void InitializeIntermediate(IfmDocument pDoc)
{
    // Initialize COM.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    IEPAccessPtr pIEPAccess(__uuidof(EPAccess));

    double result = -1;
    pIEPAccess->InitializeEP (&result);

    ...
}

static void Timestep1(...)
{
    IEPAccessPtr pIEPAccess(__uuidof(EPAccess));

    double result = -1.1;
    pIEPAccess->Timestep (...);
    ...

    // now I get a wrong result back here, because this call leads to nowhere as
    // the connector object in the dll is void
}
```

I realized that I am requesting a second instance with that line

```
IEPAccessPtr pIEPAccess(__uuidof(EPAccess));
```

So I changed that pointer to one single instance and everything is fine. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you want to maintain a single object throughout the use of dll in c. If that is the case try something similar to singleton pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

What singleton emphazises is you create only single object for a class and use it to perform all the work you need. Basically you might need a function that does something like this,

```
public class EAccess : IAccess
    {
       private static EConnector Connector
        public EConnector getConnector(){
           if(Connector == null){
               Connector = new EConnector();
            } 
             return Connector;
        }
       public double Timestep(double time, double[] values)
        {
          return getConnector().Connect();
        }

    };
```

Even though this is not the traditional way of doing things using singleton but I think it still does the work. I may be wrong. Please correct me if I have misunderstood something.